# Read in from a file and set the first word as a key in a table

Tags: lua

I'm able to read in from a file and set up a table but how do I make it so the first word of each new table slot is a key?

```
-- see if the file exists
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open("data.txt", "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

-- get all lines from a file, returns an empty
-- list/table if the file does not exist
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines("data.txt") do
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
  end
  return lines
end

local lines = lines_from(file)

-- print all line numbers and their contents
for k,v in pairs(lines) do
  print('line[' .. k .. ']', v)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how do you define word. If it is sequence of English letters, then you can go with something like this:

```
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines("data.txt") do
    first_word = string.match(line, "%a+") -- word
    lines[first_word] = line
  end
  return lines
end
```

Comment: So this sets the first word in each table to a key for that table?

Comment: @CorDell I edited the answer with modified function `lines_from()`, which sets the table according to your requirements. I read wrong first time.

Comment: So now if the file it reads in for example is Fred attack 4,(new line) Jim dodge 5... the name would be the key for each?

Comment: Yes. Now it should do exactly that (sorry, writing too fast).

Comment: All good i appreciate the help. And so now I need to read in another file which just has names and outputs the whole line for each slot in the table chosen by the second file read in

Comment: Sorry, but this question is only about reading the data into the table. For different question, please open new one question on SO.

Comment: So about this code still though if the file it is reading in to set keys, how does it know when its the first word to make the key? Can i print them so i know it is right just to be safe?

Comment: How do I print the first word? Just to check that it is doing what it should be

Comment: It should be in the `k` variable in the line `print('line[' .. k .. ']', v)`.

Comment: I get this when running it    lua: 3.lua:25: attempt to concatenate local 'k' (a function value)
stack traceback:
 3.lua:25: in main chunk
 [C]: ?

Comment: Sorry. I used `gmatch` instead of `match`. Now it should do what you need: [online preview](http://ideone.com/yb9Zuu) (there is a bit different syntax, but it works the same way).